# Have you ever gotten jquery vsdoc file to work with Visual Studio?

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2010, vsdoc

I assume the point of the jquery vsdoc file is to provide some form of intellisense for jquery.  I have used Visual Studio & jQuery & ASP.NET MVC for a while but I have never once seen it work in action. I don't know if: 1) I'm misunderstanding the purpose of the jQuery vsdoc file, 2) it doesn't work when you use jQuery from the Microsoft CDN, 3) Resharper is conflicting (I am using 6 now but it didnt work with 4,5 either) or 4) someother extension I have is causing it to not to work.

**My question:** is any form of jQuery intellisense possible with Visual Studio 2010, and if so, can you post a screenshot of what it looks like?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Just having the vsdoc file present isn't enough to enable intellisense.  You need to reference the file in your page (wrapped in `if(false)` to prevent the reference from being rendered to the client):

```
<% if(false) 
{ %>
    <script src="/path/to/vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<% } %>
```

or at the top of your .js file:

```
/// <reference path="/path/to/vsdoc.js" />
```

**EDIT:** a screenshot:
[image: jQuery Intellisense]

Another one:

[image: jQuery Intellisense]

Comment: I tried using it, and intellisense works, but the script doesn't work in the browser when testing.

Comment: @Nick the vsdoc file is purely documentation, so you'll still need the regular jQuery library referenced.

Comment: if(false)... Funny. Thanks Microsoft.

Answer (score 13):

Sometimes you'll **also** (in addition to what Kyle wrote) need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to update javascript intellisense in visual studio

Comment: Also available in edit > intellisense > update jscript intellisense for those who have non standard keyboard shortcuts